# Can we emulate logspace turing machines in FOL extended with TC bounding the number of variables?

Tags: complexity-theory, descriptive-complexity

As far as I know, Immerman showed that first-order logics extended with transitive closure (TC) captures (non deterministic) logspace (over ordered domains) [1]. That is, any database query that can be computed with $k*log(n)$ space, can be defined through a first-order logic query with TC. To show so, Immerman emulated any logspace turing machine with first-order logics with TC.

If I understood the paper correctly, the trick consists in having a predicate "Transition(Config1, Config2)" that evaluates to true if the turing machine, when its configuration corresponds to Config1, transitions to a new configuration Config2. A configuration is encoded with a set of variables encoding the working tape of the machine, the state of the machine, and head where the machine is reading. Then, through transitive closure, we can check whether from an initial configuration we can go to a configuration with an accepting state. E.g. "TransitionClosure(InitialConfig, FinalConfig)"

The thing is that, to emulate a turing machine using $k*log(n)$, memory, Immerman uses $k$ variables. The value of each variable rangs from 1 to $n$, being $n$ the maximum constant used in the database. Hence, interpreting such constant in binary, we see that it contains $log(n)$ bits. Hence, using $k$ variables Immerman is capable of encoding a memory tape of $k*log(n)$ bits.

My question is whether it would be possible to achieve a similar emulation but without augmenting the arity of the predicates, and enlarging the logic program instead. For instance, I was wondering whether it would be possible to emulate any Turing machine using $k*log(n)$ space by creating a pipeline (maybe a circuit?) of several Turing Machines using $log(n)$ space each. In terms of queries, that would mean making the "Transition_i(Config1, Config2)" predicate from one machine i, depend on whether some previous machine(s) j could go from a "TransitionClosure_j(InitialConfig, FinalConfig)", where the memory tape of the configurations is encoded by just one variable.

What do you think? Any advice or further reading would be really appreciated.

[1] https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0216051